# Using ActionLInk from inside a helper template cshtml page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Why doesn't Html.ActionLink work in the below code?  This is a page in the app_code folder,
that I am trying to call from *index.cshtml*

**LogOnUserControl.cshtml**
    @helper DisplayUserControl(){
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated ) {

```
        <span>Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!</span>
        <span>[ {@Html.ActionLink("","","")}  ]</span>

    }
    else {
        <span>[{@Html.ActionLink("","","") }]</span>

    }
    }
```

this is the line of code from *index.cshtml*.  The call itself works, if I remove the Html.ActionLink statements the site loads fine.  Is it that you can't use them in a nested page like this? How else can I generate dynamic links?

**index.cshtml**
`@LogOnUserControl.DisplayUserControl()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's the idea with this action links? Why are you passing empty strings as arguments? I suppose you want to generate SignIn, SignOut links, don't you?

Also if you want to use HTML helpers inside shared helpers that you put in the `App_Code` folder you will need to pass them as arguments because they are not available:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html

@helper DisplayUserControl(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html) {
    if (html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
        <span>
            Welcome 
            <strong>
                @html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
            </strong>
            !
        </span>
        <span>[@html.ActionLink("SignOut", "Login")]</span>
    }
    else {
        <span>[@html.ActionLink("SignIn", "Login")]</span>
    }
}
```

and to call the helper:

```
@LogOnUserControl.DisplayUserControl(Html)
```

Personally I never use such helpers (the ones you put in the `App_Code` folder). Can't see any use for them when you have partial views, editor/display templates and Html.Action helpers.

So for example you could define a partial (`~/Views/Shared/_LogOnUserControl.cshtml`):

```
@if (User.IsAuthenticated) {
    <span>
        Welcome 
        <strong>
            @User.Identity.Name
        </strong>
        !
    </span>
    <span>[@Html.ActionLink("SignOut", "Login")]</span>
}
else {
   <span>[@Html.ActionLink("SignIn", "Login")]</span>
}
```

which you would include in your layout:

```
@Html.Partial("_LogOnUserControl")
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ViewContext' and no extension method 'ViewContext' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Darin, same problem. and the empty strings were just for brevity

Comment: @Darin, is the underscore needed by the compiler or is it just a naming convention?

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain, I've totally mixed the syntax in the helper. I've updated my answer with a working code. That's what happens when I type directly in the Answer textarea of StackOverflow without actually testing my code :-) As far as the `_` is concerned, that's a convention, not required at all.

Comment: @Darin - I'm still having issues.  Trying your solution moved my problems horizontally...now `@Html.Partial("_LogOnUserControl")` indicates an error.  Cannot implicitly convert type void to object.

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain, there are two solutions: either use App_Code or if you decide to use partials remove this folder as it could have some naming collisions.

Comment: @Darin, there is no `Request` Object under `HttpContext`.

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain, hmm, sure [there is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.request.aspx).

Comment: Okay, there is no `User` under `Request` under `HttpContext`..I guess you re updated you answer. since I see no mention of `Request` any more.

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain, yeah, I updated, there's no User property of the Request object. It's a property of HttpContext or you could directly access it as User in a partial => it's simpler.